# nuget, download uncommitted dlls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I made a checkout of my project from a different location, now I noticed that I didn't commit the dll files from /packages, can I get nuget to download them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this right now is to is to remove the reference from packages.config and reinstall those packages. We're planning to support this scenario in the future (more info here http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/165).

Comment: The referenced work item is now closed; this feature is in NuGet 1.6 and newer (Enable-PackageRestore).